# Pythonnet in C# - debugger stopped when PythonEngine.Initialize() is called

Tags: c#, python.net

I tried to run Python code from c# using pythonnet. I followed this intstuction: https://somegenericdev.medium.com/calling-python-from-c-an-introduction-to-pythonnet-c3d45f7d5232 but debugger stopped when I run the line  `PythonEngine.Initialize()`. What is the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: wrap it in at try/catch block and see what is the exception, if there's no exception and it just stops, just make sure Initialize() is not async.

Comment: try\catch doesnt return anything, debuggind just stops :(

Comment: in visual studio set IDE to break on all exceptions, and I mean all, not just CLR, use vs studio community if you are not a vs studio user.